# Why does closing an Android emulator hang my computer

Tags: android-emulator

My PC becomes unusable with high CPU usage every time when I close an Android emulator.  At least two of the 3 monitors are automatically put to sleep (as if the video cable is unplugged) in this case.  The only way to get out of it is resetting the computer.  I waited as long as half an hour for the finishing of closing the emulator to no avail. It is an x86 emulator using HAXM.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Ever figure this out? Same thing is happening to me with a 6600K, 1070 & 16 GB of ram

Comment: @COYG  I changed the emulators to use Hyper-V after it was available.  Closing an emulator got significantly better.  It has been trouble free since I upgraded my PC to AMD Ryzen 7 2700.  I do not know how much of all these improvements can be attributed to emulator improvement, Windows 10 OS improvement or my PC hardware improvement.